# Certificate error: ASP.NET Core 8 WebAPI with HTTPS running in a docker container hosted on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, webapi, docker-container

I consider myself fairly new to Ubuntu/Linux. I have been struggling with this for couple of days and after googling and reading many blogs I still can't resolve it.

My WebAPI works fine with HTTP however I am trying to secure my ASP.NET Core 8 WebAPI with HTTPS running in a docker container hosted in Ubuntu 22.04. Each time I run my container I am getting the following error:

```
sudo docker compose  -f webapi-docker-demo/docker-compose-https.yaml up
WARN[0000] /home/ubuntu/webapi-docker-demo/docker-compose-https.yaml: `version` is obsolete 
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container webapi-docker-demo-docker-demo-1  Recreated                   0.0s 
Attaching to docker-demo-1
docker-demo-1  | fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
docker-demo-1  |       Hosting failed to start
docker-demo-1  |       System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
docker-demo-1  |       To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
docker-demo-1  |       For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
docker-demo-1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
docker-demo-1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func`2 useHttps, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |          at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
docker-demo-1  |          at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
docker-demo-1  | Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
docker-demo-1  | To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
docker-demo-1  | For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func`2 useHttps, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
docker-demo-1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
docker-demo-1  |    at webapi_docker_demo.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/webapi-docker-demo/Program.cs:line 33
```

I have exported the certificate as per the instructions

```
 dotnet dev-certs https -ep ~/.aspnet/https/webapi-docker-demo.pfx -p password
```

output: A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.

I can see PFX certificate in the folder: /home/.aspnet/https

I see this output when I check the certificate using the command:

```
sudo dotnet dev-certs https --check --verbose
```

output:

```
[1] Listing certificates from CurrentUser\My
[2] Found certificates: 1 certificate
    1) ABC17F48FD02C2557D86797DD14476A6DEF629AE - CN=localhost - Valid from 2024-03-21 16:45:25Z to 2025-03-21 16:45:25Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true
[3] Checking certificates validity
[4] Valid certificates: 1 certificate
    1) ABC17F48FD02C2557D86797DD14476A6DEF629AE - CN=localhost - Valid from 2024-03-21 16:45:25Z to 2025-03-21 16:45:25Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true
[5] Invalid certificates: no certificates
[6] Finished listing certificates.
A valid certificate was found: ABC17F48FD02C2557D86797DD14476A6DEF629AE - CN=localhost - Valid from 2024-03-21 16:45:25Z to 2025-03-21 16:45:25Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true
```

This is my DockerFile

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["webapi-docker-demo/webapi-docker-demo.csproj", "webapi-docker-demo/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./webapi-docker-demo/webapi-docker-demo.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/webapi-docker-demo"
RUN dotnet build "./webapi-docker-demo.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./webapi-docker-demo.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "webapi-docker-demo.dll"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    docker-demo:
    
        image:
            webapi-docker-demo-https:v1
        ports:
            - 8081:8080
            - 8082:8081
        environment:
             - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080
             - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8081
#            - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
             - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=p@$$w0rd
             - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificate__Default__Path=/https/webapi-docker-demo.pfx
      
        volumes:
             - ~/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

I am not sure what and where I am doing incorrect. I am following the instructions at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-6.0#macos-or-linux

All these instructions works in Windows hosted Docker  but can make it work on Ubuntu hosted docker.
Any insight to the solution will be great